# Printing From VIP fails to print

Tags: printing, bluetooth, zebra-printers, motorola

I am working with MC9500 Motorola handhelds, Zebra RW-420 printers, and the VIP Application.  When I go to print a test page it reads the error:
Failed to read 1 byte(0 read)

Troubleshooting:
-I have successfully printed from other RW-420 printers
-Sent the printers that had this error back to Zebra(now they can print via Bluetooth but still show that error)
-Made sure I have the correct COM Ports
-Reset the printers multiple times on the Zebra Setup Utilities
-I have updated the firmware on the printer
-Tried changing the printer language but nothing helps

I have tried searching for this error but I haven't seen anything relevant yet.  Please let me know if there is anything I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

There was a different way to change the printer language and a few other configuration settings that needed to be changed beforehand.